# Identifly list item for css usage?

Tags: html, css

see, i build my own website using just html and css. I'm figuring out most things on my own but i can't find a way to solve this problem, i guess because of my limited knowledge. I have this simple list:

```
<ul class="nav">  
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
  <li><a href="maps.html">PARKING</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">DOGS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>  
</ul>
```

I now want to change the appearance of the third item when it is clicked, therefore i somehow need to identify it, so i can stylize it like below:

```
.nav > li > a {
text-decoration:none;
font-size: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Like in this example above, i want to stylize the appearance, but not for all items, just for one. 
Can you help me out? Sorry if i wasn't clear enough..

Comment: Why not use a class?  That's what they're for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd add a class to it and style based on that. No reason to get super specific with selectors here.

```
<li><a href="maps.html" class="parking">Parking</a></li>
```

Then in your CSS you can do:

```
.parking:active {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for, simple but effective!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:nth-child` pseudo-class with the `:active` pseudo-class to target the third list item link:

```css
.nav > li:nth-child(3):active > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="maps.html">PARKING</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">DOGS</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why resort to `:nth-child(3)` and `>` here if they have control of the markup? It creates needlessly specific selectors.

Comment: @BillCriswell I don't see anything wrong with the specificity. It's a bit belt and suspenders here but I'm not seeing a reason not to use it.

Comment: It's more fragile and more difficult to overwrite though. You might as well add `html > body > #container > .etc > .etc` as well if we're going by reasons "not to use it" though.

Comment: @j08691 I agree.  The reason not to use it is because of sustainability.  Nothing about `nth-child(3)` indicates "style this differently because it links out to a map".  If the list is dynamic and another list item is added before the maps link, it'll break.  That's less likely the case with a class.  It's still good to have multiple ways to do the same thing, so the answer is still useful, but if possible, OP should probably use a class.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the OP's comment "I now want to change the appearance of the third item when it is clicked"

Comment: That's a fair argument. If they wanted to always style the middle one `nth-child` would be the right approach. Need some clarification I suppose. I just don't get the feeling that's the case.